# "Source file could not be read" error when downloading a file with Firefox

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox, download

I am attempting to download a file with Firefox and I see this error:

> C:\Users\Lynda\Desktop\Sample.psd.zip.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read.
>
> Try again later, or contact the server administrator.

I see this happen quite a bit and very sporadic from many different sites.

What is going on and why does this happen?

Note I am using Firefox 15, but have seen this error for several versions. Also I am on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Does it happen in a different browser? Have you tried reinstalling Firefox? What else have you tried?

Comment: @RandolphWest - Have not tried other browsers but I was attempting to update VLC and it gave me an error saying the download file was corrupted. Have not seen that error before and assume they are related. I will attempt to use another browser to nail down the error. And yes I have re-installed FF since this has happened.

Comment: Can you please test if this is a SourceForge problem? I've noticed that sometimes, the SF location you're directed to can time out on occasion. I know that VLC uses SF as their download partner.

Comment: @RandolphWest - This is more than a SF problem as I have seen it across many many sites.

Comment: Make sure you try all the steps in http://kb.mozillazine.org/Source_file_could_not_be_read .  Also, you can try disabling the windows security policy check -- in "about:config", set "browser.download.manager.scanWhenDone" to false.

Comment: I have this problem. It happens all across the internet. Trying the download in any other browser is without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to download this file using Internet Explorer to have a try.
Remember to turn off Pop-up Blocker on the Privacy tab.
In addition, you may need install a application to open ZIP file.

Comment: How does this help the OP? They are able to start the download but it fails part way through.